# how to change or replace class attr?

Tags: jquery

i have problem to display option class default selected when load page and to replace class default?
first I'm a newbie. this my code

```js
function myView(sel) {
$("#colomView").addClass(sel.value);
};
function myView2(sel) {
$("#colomView").addClass(sel.value);
};
```

```css
.redBG {
    background-color:red;
    padding:10px;
}
.blueBG {
    background-color:blue;
    padding:10px;
}
.redBOX{
    border:1px solid red;
}
.blueBOX{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="colomView" class="">
    <p>HERE DEFAULT TEXT</p>
    <select onchange="myView(this);">
        <option selected="selected" value="redBG">redBG</option>
        <option value="blueBG">blueBG</option>
    </select>
    <select onchange="myView2(this);">
        <option selected="selected" value="redBOX">redBG</option>
        <option value="blueBOX">blueBG</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

the problem : how to replace class from attr? if i click blueBOX then i click redBOX, result will be class="blueBOX redBOX".

please help solve my problem? thanks

Comment: to get the value of a dropdown in jquery use `.val()` instead of `.value`

Comment: @Mivaweb But here in `sel.value`, `sel` is a DOM node, so it is better

Comment: @A.Wolff correct I look over the `this` part where there is no `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

To use jQuery, you need to include it. Then you could use:

```
$("#colomView").attr('class', sel.value);
```

if no other class need to be set on this element.
http://jsfiddle.net/wuj5tfwo/

If you want to 'toggle' only this two specific classes, then you can use:

```
$("#colomView").removeClass('redBG blueBG').addClass(sel.value);
```

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by `change style`?

Comment: i want to modify class like class="redBG blueBOX" where .blueBOX{border:1px solid blue} and have two selectbox

Comment: If i understand your expected behaviour, then see e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/wuj5tfwo/3/  or http://jsfiddle.net/wuj5tfwo/2/ if you don't want to trigger it on document ready

Answer (score 0):

On changing the selected box first you have to remove all the classes present in class attribute of 'colomView' div, then u have to assign selected options class,

Try this code ,

```js
function myView(sel) {
    $("#colomView").attr('class',sel.value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vtu1qaf8/1/) please.

You should use `attr('class', className);` `className` will be the name of the class you want to assign, in order to replace the default class.

Hope it helps.